# QSettings registry and redirect on regedit 64bit (Wow6432)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, registry, qsettings

I'm developing an application using the Qt framework. One of the features is to get all registry from `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` using QSettings.

When I was testing, I found something curious:
My code get the path "`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`", in other words, `QSettings registry("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall", QSettings::NativeForm)`, and print it to json file. Until then, it's ok. But when I open the regedit.exe and I go to the same path, the values are different. My application don't collect that information.

So I went researching and found something, windows do a redirection of this path to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows`, and that path (64bits path) apparently is inaccessible.

Anyone knows how can I get around this problem still using QSettings? Some registry, like WinRAR, are not collected because it.

Thanks, sry about the bad english.

Comment: [32-bit and 64-bit Application Data in the Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072.aspx)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I saw it, but it's not possible pass this flags using QSettings. :/

Comment: Your app is 32-bit, correct?

Comment: Well, since you are clearly writing Windows-specific code anyway, drop down to WinAPI.

Comment: One simple solution would be to make a 64-bit helper app that reads the same registry key(s) in 64-bit mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598466/qt-write-to-registry-32-64-issue

Comment: @MrEricSir I afraid it happen. I'll try that. Thanks.